# focus() function is not working for input fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-form-validator

I have a modal appointment form and applied form validation inside javascript. Their `alert()` function is working fine but `focus()` function is not working for input fields. I have searched and applied several times for making a solution but not working.

**Here is my html code**

```
<form id="appointment-form" action="" method="get" style="margin-top: 3rem;">
            <div class="left-agileits-w3layouts same">
                <div class="gaps">
                    <p>Patient Name</p>
                    <input type="text" id="patient_name" name="Patient Name" placeholder="" style="border-left:2px solid #0B6FB2"/>
                    <div id="patient_name_error" class="val_error"></div>
                </div>  
                <div class="gaps">  
                    <p>Phone Number</p>
                    <input type="text" id="patient_number" name="Number" placeholder="" style="border-left:2px solid #0B6FB2"/>
                    <div id="patient_number_error" class="val_error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="gaps">
                    <p>Email</p>
                    <input type="email" id="patient_email" name="email" placeholder="" style="border-left:2px solid #0B6FB2"/>
                    <div id="patient_email_error" class="val_error"></div>
                </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <center>
                    <button id="add" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Make an appointment" style="padding: 16px 20px 20px 20px; color: #fff; margin-top:20px;">Make an appointment
                    </button>
                </center>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Here is my jQuery code**

```
$('#add').click(function(event){

        var patient_name = $('#patient_name').val();
        var patient_number = $('#patient_number').val();
        var patient_email = $('#patient_email').val();

        if(patient_name.trim() == '' )
        {
           alert('Please enter your name.');
           $('#patient_name').focus();
           return false;
        }
        else if(patient_number.trim() == '' )
        {
           alert('Please enter your number.');
           $('#patient_number').focus();
           return false;
        }
        else if(patient_email.trim() == '' )
        {
           alert('Please enter your email.');
           $('#patient_email').focus();
           return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Works fine on chrome with newest jQuery. Which browser are you using? Which jQuery version?

Comment: @MantasČekanauskas....Ya works fine....focus is working....there is no problem with the code. Bcz of not using any focus color I can't understand first.

Comment: Yeah... it seems to work in the current version of FireFox. What do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect to happen; what is happening? If you open up the developer console are there any error messages? If so what do they say? What do you mean by "focus color"? Were you expecting the field to be highlighted? `.focus()` just moves the input focus to the element, if you want to highlight it you'll have to do something like adding a class to it that changes the appearance of the element.